# facebook api using python

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api, pyfacebook

I would like to know how to write python code for fetching the likes, comments, etc. on a post of Facebook posts. I am using the `pyfacebook` interface but when I run some code using this in python it gives me an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ts.py", line 2, in <module>
    import facebook
  File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/facebook/__init__.py", line 58, in <module>
ImportError: No module named django.conf
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try [facebook-sdk](https://github.com/pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk), follow the example, you can get anything you want in the [Facebook Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/).

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a web framework called *Django* installed on your system to use `pyfacebook`.

However: it appears that Python is viewed by some to be the [wrong tool for the job](http://www.robertames.com/blog.cgi/entries/pyfacebook-tutorials-suck.html), noting that;

> if you’re not in PHP, you’re already a half-step behind. It looks like the PHP libraries + integration are pretty good, well tested, well documented, etc.

As well as:

> [the] pyfacebook tutorial is really a django tutorial.

You may want to look into [installing Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/install/), and starting from there. I would recommend *not* straying from the official Django tutorial, as it is a very good one.

Comment: i am getting same error after installing django aswell..i just want to fetch the likes,comment made by my friends on my post, its related to my project ...so if u have any python code or php code prefrebly python,plz give